# Clustering text-embedding-ada-002

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, openai-api, review

What would be the best approach to cluster the reviews sentences embeddings generated with text-embedding-ada-002. K-means seems to be mot the best approach as here its very hard to define the best number of clusters upfront.

I want to cluster sentences based on their similarity

Do you have any ideas? This is open for discussion question!

For now I have just tried k-means (problem is you need to predefine number of clusters), and fast clustering  (did not work well with ada embeddings, but maube I am doing somehting wrong)

```
import torch

from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
model = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

# corpus_embeddings = model.encode(corpus_sentences, batch_size=64, show_progress_bar=True, convert_to_tensor=True)
embeddings = torch.Tensor(df_exploded['ada_v2'].tolist())
clusters = util.community_detection(embeddings, min_community_size=40, threshold=0.75)
```